# Keras does not work with 3 or more dimentions. InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I want to create a model that takes a matrix of shape (64, 4) to predict an array of shape (4). But it does not work for some reason. For example, here a code:

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers, optimizers

x = np.random.uniform(size=600*64*4).reshape(600, 64, 4)
y = np.random.uniform(size=600*4).reshape(600, 4)

model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=[64, 4]),
    layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(4)
])
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=["mae"])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=5)
```

And this script ends with `InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32,64,4] vs. [32,4]`
But the code below:

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers, optimizers

x = np.random.uniform(size=600*4).reshape(600, 4)
y = np.random.uniform(size=600*4).reshape(600, 4)

model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=[4]),
    layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(4)
])
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=["mae"])
model.fit(x, y, epochs=5)
```

... works just fine. It is seems for me there is a logical mistake in such behavior. Or maybe I do not understand something.

Please, help.

Comment: You should add the imports when asking about code. Here `import numpy as np` and `from tensorflow.keras import models, layers, optimizers` would have been nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works,

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(size=600*64*4).reshape(600, 64, 4)
y = np.random.uniform(size=600*4).reshape(600, 4)

ip = Input(shape=(64,4))
d1 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(ip)
f = Flatten()(d1)
d2 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(f)
d3 = Dense(4)(d2)

model = Model(ip, d3)

model.compile(loss='mse', metrics='mae', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

model.fit(x,y,epochs=1, batch_size = 64)
```

You're using Dense in a wrong manner, FC layers except for single-dimensional data mostly also you need to flatten in some layer so your last output is consistent with `y`.

```
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 64, 4)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 64, 16)            80        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 16)                16400     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 68        
=================================================================
Total params: 16,548
Trainable params: 16,548
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1689 - mae: 0.3340

<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f838cd4deb8>
```

Check out the Flatten layer makes sure your output of the model is 2-d (batch_size, num_class, or output_nodes). But without flattening you've 3-d output from the model so you must make y 3-d too.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you have 2D features (64x4) and 4 1D outputs. Since your model is a series of simple matrix multiplications you are not transforming the 2D data to 1D. You need to either apply layers like RNNs or CNNs that model relationships in both directions in your data and then reshape it, or just plain reshape it.

I recommend writing up each tensor on a piece of paper with their shape in subscript. You'll quickly find that if you were to get the dot product of each one in the order you have there then the shapes are incompatible.

EDIT: To make it clearer - run `model.summary()` before `model.fit()`. You'll see that the first Dense layer outputs [32, 64, 16] and the same for the second Dense. The last outputs [32, 64, 4] and to find the loss Tensorflow has to compare that tensor to the labels that you are providing. But they are shaped [32, 4]. You can't subtract a 3 by 8 matrix from a 2 by 5 matrix and likewise for tensors of different rank and dimensions (which is what you need to do here - your loss is literally a sum of (absolute value of) subtractions).